# How to see cache data on Windows using predis on Laravel website?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, predis

I am using Windows 10 and I have installed Redis. When opening the Redis client and typing "keys *", I see the data from one of my websites. Unfortunately, I cannot see the cached data of my second website.

On both websites, there is installed the "predis/predis": "^1.1" Package.

The first website, where I see the cached data in Redis Client, is using Laravel 5.8

Here is the configuration:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

The second website is migrated to Laravel 8. The data is cached because in the Debugbar I see the reduced number of queries.
Here is the configuration:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
```

On this website, I have also a problem deleting all the cached data from my CacheController. I am calling:

```
Cache::flush();
```

But it doesn't seem to flush the cache.

Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Check your `cache` config you see if the redis cache connection is used. Than look into your `database` config, go to redis settings and check the `cache` connection. Check the value of the `database`, this normally defaults to `1`. Inside redis-cli, make sure you type `SELECT 1` to access that db. Now check if your cache data is there.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman thank you very much. Yes, that helped me. I mean the "select 1". Without typing this, I see the cache of my other website.